# Error Minting Native Asset: " unexpected '.', expecting space, letter or digit, white space, "+" or end of input "

Tags: cardano-cli, native-assets

I am writing a script to automate minting native assets. Everything works well, up until this point:

```
echo "Building transaction..."
cardano-cli transaction build \
            --babbage-era \
            $NETWORK \
            --tx-in $txhash#$txix \
            --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenhash" \
            --mint "$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenhash" \
            --minting-script-file "$tokenname"/policy/policy.script \
            --change-address $address \
            --out-file "$tokenname"/tx.build;
```

but every time I run the script, I get this error for "--tx-out":

```
Building transaction...
option --tx-out: 
unexpected '.'
expecting space, letter or digit, white space, "+" or end of input
```

I followed the [official Cardano documentation](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/) for how to format the command, but for some reason the 'dot' between $policyid and $tokenhash is giving issues.

Is there something I'm missing? I know the documentation can be notoriously out of date, but nothing I've found online and elsewhere has helped so far.

Comment: have you tried substituting the variables with actual values? Could possibly be caused by empty value in one of the variables on tx-out line

Comment: Try echoing all those evnvironment variables to make sure none of the have a `.` character.

Comment: Okay, tried the suggestions, now the error I'm getting "Command failed: transaction build  Error: The script language SimpleScriptLanguage SimpleScriptV1 is not supported in the Babbage era."